# MySql Connection in C++ Visual 2015

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-studio-2015

I've downloaded MySql.Data via nuget packet manager, I got my Sql server running in the background, but i still can't use any methods from that package in code. I've tried adding it somehow by references folder in solution window, but it seems like nothing is there. I've tried also ' using namespace MySql::Data::MySqlClient;' but it doesn't work neither. Could anybody tell me how to import this properly?

/EDIT
I downloaded MySql.Data package via NUGET packet manager in visual studio 2015, yet i still can't acces methods from this package in my project. What else do I have to do, to make this happen( acces methods from this package)

Comment: your post is unclean. Please format it and read FAQ

Comment: Since you didn't post any code, I believe you have to write code to *make this happen*.